# APEX JSON Generator writeString escapes quotes

Tags: json, salesforce, apex-code

Is there a way NOT to escape the quotes in a string when using JSON Generator's method `writeString`? I'm getting the following result:

```
"{\"Name\":\"asdsads\",\"Query\":\"adasdasd\"},{\"Name\":\"12312312\",\"Query\":\"3123123\"},{\"Name\":\"d23d2\",\"Query\":\"3d23d2\"}"
```

instead of:

```
{"Name":"asdsads","Query":"adasdasd"},{"Name":"12312312","Query":"3123123"},{"Name":"d23d2","Query":"3d23d2"}
```

I have tried `replace('\\', '');` as well as `replace('\\"', '"');` but didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tell us more about what you're trying to do. Can you serialize an object or do you have to manually build the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Had to do the following:

```
String genString = gen.getAsString();
genString = genString.replace('\\"', '"');
genString = genString.replace('"{', '{');
genString = genString.replace('}"', '}');
```

Replacing on the fly didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Its better not to add in the above snippet in the RestResource Class rather I recommend to add this snippet before you parse the Json.
It worked fine for me as i have the Json Generated from RestResource class.

"{\n "Status" : "Success",\n "Count" : 6,\n "Accounts" : [ "AccontFromMyVF", "United Oil & Gas, UK", "United Oil & Gas, Singapore", "United Oil & Gas Corp.", "AccontFromMyVF", "AccontFromMyVF12" ]\n}"

after adding the below

```
   Accountresult = Accountresult.replace('\\n', '');
    Accountresult = Accountresult.replace('\\"', '"');
    Accountresult = Accountresult.replace('"{', '{');
    Accountresult = Accountresult.replace('}"', '}');
```

My response turned into

{ "Status" : "Success", "Count" : 6, "Accounts" : [ "AccontFromMyVF", "United Oil & Gas, UK", "United Oil & Gas, Singapore", "United Oil & Gas Corp.", "AccontFromMyVF", "AccontFromMyVF12" ]}

from this Json we can easily perform parse actions